# How do i get the "about me" field via facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Why i can't get the "about me" field via Facebook API?
My access token has a user_about_me permission.

[image: API method]

And the same access token is working with FQL.

[image: FQL]

Comment: **Don't use it now, because it is now deprecated** https://stackoverflow.com/a/49816462/5653015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Authorize with the `user_about_me` permission
- Make sure there´s actually content in the "About me" section

If that still does not work, you should file a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Edit: I just did some testing and it does look like it´s a bug. I do have content in the "About me" section and it does not show up. I did find out that the field "bio" lists the content of my "About me" section though:

```
/me?fields=id,bio
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_about_me mentions it drive-by style, by saying, _“Provides access to a person's personal description (the 'About Me' section on their Profile) through the `bio` property on the `User` object.”_ – but I think the docs for `User` should reflect that, too.

Comment: thanx for the information. it´s weird though that there is an "about" field in the user table too...

Comment: Since I’m in a bug filing mood today – https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1082119618519083/

Answer (score 1):

I got the same question, the answer is actually deprecated for version 2.8 or higher. You will see this message:

```
{
error: {
message: "(#12) bio field is deprecated for versions v2.8 and higher",
type: "OAuthException",
code: 12,
fbtrace_id: "Aclo0ndp39/"
}
}
```

So in order to have the biography you just have to:

```
/me?fields=id,about
```