# Invalid Scope user_about_me, this message is only shown to developers, Users of your app will ignore these permission if present

Tags: facebook

I am getting this Error on Facebook Login.

[see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85x9d.png)

Comment: file:///home/agc-linux/Desktop/facebookError.png

Comment: not sure what that means...we obviously cannot open a file on your computer ;) - just check out my answer.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/85x9d.png Check this

Comment: i know, the error is very well known. invalid means the scope does not exist. again, read my answer.

Comment: [I dwonvoted because an image of your exception is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/).

Answer (score 8):

Don´t use a scope that does not exist (anymore).

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#4-4-2018